# Why am I getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with AmazonSQS?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

My code is:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;

AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError AmazonSQSClientBuilder
```

I am not new to Java but experiencing this strange error

Build is good but this is the runtime error that I get

thanks for any help!

Comment: Is it a maven/gradle project? Can you share your configuration file (pom.xml etc) with us?

Comment: You can also follow these examples from Amazon. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/java/example_code/sqs

Comment: thanks Vitor.  This is not a maven or gradle project, IntelliJ instead.  I have the same problem with an example from Amazon source code. Very strange